Change picker backgroundcolor based on selection
I have two pickers, one is for priority and the other one is for the selection of a date. I want to change the background of both pickers based on the selection of the priority picker, as example if the priority is high the picker should be red, middle orange and so on...
Currently I can only manually set the background color of the picker with an initializer.
This is my code for the View:
struct AddWunschSheetView: View {
    
    @State private var titelTextField: String = ""
    @State private var kostenTextField: String = ""
    
    @State private var sliderValue = 1.0
    @State private var amount = 0.5
    
    @State private var prioPicker = 1
    @State private var selection = 1
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    init() {
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.red
        
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key:Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ]
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .selected)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section("Artikeldetails") {
                    TextField("", text: $titelTextField, prompt: Text("Titel des Artikels"))
                }
                
                Section("Priority") {
                    Picker("", selection: $prioPicker) {
                        Text("Dringend").tag(1)
                        Text("Hoch").tag(2)
                        Text("Mittel").tag(3)
                        Text("Niedrig").tag(4)
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                }
                
                Picker("", selection: $selection) {
                    Text("Tag").tag(1)
                    Text("Woche").tag(2)
                    Text("Monat").tag(3)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                
                if selection == 1 {
                    Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 1...31, step: 1.0, minimumValueLabel: Text("1"), maximumValueLabel: Text("31"), label: {})
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                } else if selection == 2 {
                    Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 1...52, step: 1.0, minimumValueLabel: Text("1"), maximumValueLabel: Text("52"), label: {})
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                } else if selection == 3 {
                    Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 1...12, step: 1.0, minimumValueLabel: Text("1"), maximumValueLabel: Text("12"), label: {})
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text( String(format: "%.0f", sliderValue))
                    if selection == 1 {
                        Text("Tage bis zum Ereigniss")
                    } else if selection == 2 {
                        Text("Wochen bis zum Ereigniss")
                    } else if selection == 3 {
                        Text("Monate bis zum Ereigniss")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Kosten")
                            .bold()
                        TextField("", text: $kostenTextField, prompt: Text("0€"))
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                            .padding(.top)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    if prioPicker == 1 {
                        Gauge(value: amount) {
                            Text("50%")
                        }
                        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
                        .tint(.red)
                    } else if prioPicker == 2 {
                        Gauge(value: amount) {
                            Text("50%")
                        }
                        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
                        .tint(.orange)
                    } else if prioPicker == 3 {
                        Gauge(value: amount) {
                            Text("50%")
                        }
                        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
                        .tint(.blue)
                    } else if prioPicker == 4 {
                        Gauge(value: amount) {
                            Text("50%")
                        }
                        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
                        .tint(.green)
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Neuen Artikel hinzufügen")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The UI looks like this:

I have already tried to customize the init with if-statements, I've tried to customize the sections, pickers,...
I am not even sure if this is possible.

It is difficult to add styling to a segmented Picker, as you have discovered. However, what you could do is use the same technique as shown in the answer to Segmented picker in iOS - handle tap on already selected item (it was my answer):

instead of showing the color in the background, show it as an overlay in the foreground
the label of the selected item also needs to be shown
move the overlay into position using .matchedGeometryEffect
hidden placeholders are used as the source for the .matchedGeometryEffect
to work effectively, the overlay needs to be animated in exactly the same way as the native selection indicator; I found that .spring(duration: 0.28) corresponds pretty closely.

The .matchedGeometryEffect requires a namespace:
@Namespace private var ns

Your previous init with legacy UI calls is no longer needed
//    init() {
//        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.red
//
//        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key:Any] = [
//            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
//        ]
//        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .selected)
//    }

I would suggest creating an enum for your priority levels, something like:
enum Priority: CaseIterable {
    case dringend
    case hoch
    case mittel
    case niedrig

    var asString: String {
        "\(self)".capitalized
    }

    var color: Color {
        switch self {
        case .dringend: .red
        case .hoch: .orange
        case .mittel: .blue
        case .niedrig: .green
        }
    }
}

This enum should be used for the state variable that holds the priority selection:
@State private var prioPicker = Priority.dringend

The Picker can then be assembled as follows:
Section("Priority") {
    Picker("", selection: $prioPicker) {
        ForEach(Priority.allCases, id: \.self) { priority in
            Text(priority.asString)
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
    .background {

        // A row of placeholders
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Priority.allCases, id: \.self) { priority in
                Color.clear
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: priority, in: ns, isSource: true)
            }
        }
    }
    .overlay {
        ZStack {
            prioPicker.color
            Text(prioPicker.asString)
                .font(.footnote)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: prioPicker, in: ns, isSource: false)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7))
        .animation(.spring(duration: 0.28), value: prioPicker)
    }
}

The Gauge can also be simplified:
Gauge(value: amount) {
    Text("50%")
}
.gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
.tint(prioPicker.color)

The same approach can also be used for the segmented picker used to select the period, but giving it the color from the selected priority:
enum Period: CaseIterable {
    case tag
    case woche
    case monat

    var asString: String {
        "\(self)".capitalized
    }

    var maxSliderVal: Int {
        switch self {
        case .tag: 31
        case .woche: 52
        case .monat: 12
        }
    }
}

@State private var selection = Period.tag

Picker("", selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(Period.allCases, id: \.self) { period in
        Text(period.asString)
    }
}
.pickerStyle(.segmented)
.background {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(Period.allCases, id: \.self) { period in
            Color.clear
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: period, in: ns, isSource: true)
        }
    }
}
.overlay {
    ZStack {
        prioPicker.color
        Text(selection.asString)
            .font(.footnote)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selection, in: ns, isSource: false)
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7))
    .animation(.spring(duration: 0.28), value: selection)
}

Slider(
    value: $sliderValue,
    in: 1...Double(selection.maxSliderVal),
    step: 1.0,
    minimumValueLabel: Text("1"),
    maximumValueLabel: Text("\(selection.maxSliderVal)"),
    label: {}
)
.padding(.horizontal)
.onChange(of: selection.maxSliderVal) { oldVal, newVal in
    sliderValue = min(sliderValue, Double(newVal))
}

HStack {
    Spacer()
    Text( String(format: "%.0f", sliderValue))
    if selection == .tag {
        Text("Tage bis zum Ereigniss")
    } else if selection == .woche {
        Text("Wochen bis zum Ereigniss")
    } else if selection == .monat {
        Text("Monate bis zum Ereigniss")
    }
    Spacer()
}

Here's how it all looks:

It is interesting to note, that when the RoundedRectangle clip shape is applied to the ZStack, the shape automatically adopts square corners for the inner edges. However, if you would prefer the shape to have four rounded corners in all positions, you just need to move the .clipShape to the color instead.

Thank you very much, it works perfectly! I hope apple will one day import the feature to easily change the colors. However, your solution works really fine, good idea to make it like that. :)
